# Unable to update the text area field from apex

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

we have this code in catch block, the requirement is to capture the error before throwing the error to lwc component in a field.

```
Repair_Repaired_Vehicle_Cost__c cost = new Repair_Repaired_Vehicle_Cost__c( 
    Id = String.valueOf(apinameToObject.get('id')),
    Rule_Failed_for_debug__c = 'Record transfer failed due to the repair criteria: ' + criteriaId + ' Formula:' + criteriaExpression + 'Error Message ' +e.getMessage()
);

update cost;

throw new AuraHandledException('Record transfer failed due to the repair criteria: ' +criteriaId +' Formula:' +criteriaExpression +'Error Message ' +e.getMessage());
```

But the value is not reflected in the field, FLS is not read-only, checked the debug in trigger the value is coming, but still not able to see the value.

I think i am doing some silly mistake in updating the record but not getting it.

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception after updating the record? Doing that should cause the entire transaction to be rolled back (thus undoing the update you're trying to make).

Comment: i just want to capture the error, this method is used in lwc controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An uncaught exception will roll back almost all database transactions, with the single exception of Platform Events that are set to Deliver Immediately. You have two basic options here.

## Global Error Handler/Client-Side Logging

You can use a [global error handler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_error) to catch any errors and log them, or you can make a separate server call in your catch blocks:

```
// Sub-Option 1
async errorCallback(error, stack) {
  await logServerError({ error, stack }) // This would be an Apex method
}
// Sub-Option 2
try {
  let result = await myApexMethod({ params })
} catch(error) {
  await logError({error}) // A separate Apex method to log errors
}
```

This allows you to catch even governor limit messages.

## Platform Event

A Platform Event set to "Deliver Immediately" will persist through a thrown, uncaught exception. You can set a trigger on this to perform logging at that time.

```
// This is Apex code
Logger__e log = new Logger__e(Message__c='blah blah blah');
EventBus.publish(log);
throw new AuraHandledException('blah blah blah');
```

Comment: With the first approach, there is a chance that user can see what the error is, if he can open console and look at network tab and all that. Although that might not be a big concern many times.